# Remote Attestation for Windows

Tags: security, tpm

I am building a distributed application in which the software is installed by my company on our customer's hardware. The customer can therefore tamper with the software. I would like to know if a technique exists so that when the software running on customer hardware make a web request to our central server (i.e. totally under our control), that we can validate that the request is coming from an untampered version of our software.

I believe that this is referred to as "remote attestation." Web searches about remote attestation return a variety of results, from "it is not possible" to "use the TPM". But I have not been able to find a simple to understand example of how to code this in Windows.

So, my question is: Is remote attestation possible in Windows, and if so, is there a working example that I can use as the basis for implementation?

Note: Remote attestation is sometimes achieved through "obscuration" techniques such as embedding a "shared secret" into the application and then obscuring it in various ways to try and ensure that an attacker cannot easily extract that shared secret through de-compiling etc. I am not interested in such techniques and am looking for something that provides real security not security through obscurity.

Comment: BTW - I am aware that there seems to be some support for remote attestation in the Linux community. In particular, OpenStack appears to provide a library for this (https://01.org/blogs/tlcounts/2014/openattestation-oat-project). But I am specifically interested in Windows implementations.

Answer (score 0):

In order to attestate a system you need 2 things:

1. A chain of trust from a root of trust up to every executed code and
2. Means to interpret and verify the obtained measurements on your server.

When using Windows you have neither.

Currently not even Windows itself is aware of its sate. However, that improved in Windows 8. Now you have measurements of the boot loader and drivers at least. But nothing that extends to user code.